# Iterate over all pixels to check which pixels are white and which are black

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to iterate over an image with only black and white pixels. For every black pixel I want to decrease a score, while for each white pixel I would like to increase a score. However upon testing the following code I get this error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous.
```

It has something to do with the `img[i, j]` statement. How can there be multiple pixels in that aray? Am I not specifically calling one pixel by using `img[i,j]`? Does someone know how I could fix this, or if there is another working method for accessing 1 specific pixel?

```
def score(img):
    score = 0

    height, width, _ = img.shape
    for i in range(height):
        for j in range(width):
            if img[i, j] == [255,255,255]:
                score = score + 1
            else:
                score = score - 1
    print(score)
```

The image was read using the openCV library. The original image is then filtered for a specific color, with which a mask is created. This mask only has black and white pixels, as mentioned before.

```
img = cv2.imread("images/test.jpg")
mask = cv2.inRange(img, lower_bound, upper_bound)
```

Comment: `img` has three dimensions, so `img[i, j]` is not a single value, but a vector. If the third dimension is `1`, you can just do `img[i, j, 0]` instead. However, in that case, you can just do `score = 2 * np.count_nonzero(img) - img.size`.

Comment: First of all `print(score)` won't work, also can you please show which library (at least, best will be how you define) you use to create the image

Comment: The indentation of the print was wrong, I fixed it. To create the image I used openCV. I will update the question.

Comment: Variable and function name are same.. Not a good idea!

Comment: there are opencv api to query the image format, the number of channels, the depth ecc. Please do that and, after, update your question, the following answers have no sense if you do not specify the details of the image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because `img[i, j]` gives an array with the RGB values

img[i, j] = [0, 0, 0]        # for black

img[i, j] = [255, 255, 255]  # for white

And these arrays are not associated to `True` or `False`. You need to change your condition.

```
>>> img[0,0] == [0,0,0]
array([ True,  True,  True])
>>> all(img[0,0] == [0,0,0])
True
```

Your condition needs an `all()`.

Comment: I changed the if-test to `if img[i,j] == [255,255,255]:` but still the same error

Comment: It's an array, not a list, more like array([255, 255, 255])

Comment: Hmm strange, even with `numpy.array([255,255,255])` no difference

Comment: My bad, just realized the comparison gives an array, you need to surround it with all() to get one value.

Answer (score 0):

It means that your array has got 3 dimension. You can print `img[i,j]` to see how it looks like. The value you want is probably often at the same position so calling `img[i,j,0]` or `img[i,j,1]` should work

Comment: If I change my if-test to `if img[i,j,0] == [255,255,255]:` or `if img[i,j,1] == [255,255,255]:` it still gives me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go =^..^=

```
from PIL import Image

# load image
img = Image.open('BlackWhite.gif').convert('RGB')
pixel = img.load()

# calculate the score
score = 0
w=img.size[0]
h=img.size[1]
for i in range(w):
  for j in range(h):
      if pixel[i, j] == (255, 255, 255):
          score += 1
      elif pixel[i, j] == (0, 0, 0):
          score -= 1
```